# Compare list with dictionary and output true and false

Tags: python, list, dictionary, generator

I have a list set with dates like this:

```
listdates = [datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), datetime.date(2016, 4, 27)]
```

I have a dictionary with dates set like this:

```
dictdates = {'S1': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), datetime.date(2016, 4, 28), datetime.date(2016, 4, 29)], 'W26': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)], 'W24': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)]}
```

I want to compare the list to the dictionary and if a value from the list matches a value in the dictionary it should print unavailable.

I have the following working:

```
for val in listdates:
   if val in dictdates['S1']:
      print val, 'unavailable'
   else:
      print val, 'available'
```

This gives the output of:

```
2016-04-23 unavailable
2016-04-24 unavailable
2016-04-25 unavailable
2016-04-26 unavailable
2016-04-27 unavailable
```

What I'd like instead, is to go over every list in the dictionary and output the key with available/unavailable, like this:

```
S1
2016-04-23 unavailable
2016-04-24 unavailable
2016-04-25 unavailable
2016-04-26 unavailable
2016-04-27 unavailable

W26
2016-04-23 unavailable
2016-04-24 unavailable
2016-04-25 unavailable
2016-04-26 unavailable
2016-04-27 unavailable

W24
2016-04-23 available
2016-04-24 available
2016-04-25 unavailable
2016-04-26 available
2016-04-27 available

etc ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops through the dictionary and the list inside this loop and outputs the info you're looking for

```
for key, value in dictdates.items():
    print key
    for val in listdates:
       if val in value:
          print val, 'unavailable'
       else:
          print val, 'available'
    print "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

listdates = [datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), datetime.date(2016, 4, 27)]
dictdates = {'S1': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), datetime.date(2016, 4, 28), datetime.date(2016, 4, 29)], 'W26': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)], 'W24': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)]}

for key in dictdates:
    print key
    for val in listdates:
        if val in dictdates[key]:
            print val, 'unavailable'
        else:
            print val, 'available'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the keys of the dictionary as well:

```
for key, dates in dictdates.items():
    print key
    for val in listdates:
       if val in dates:
          print val, 'unavailable'
       else:
          print val, 'available'
```

Comment: Minor improvement: Since this is Py2, use `.iteritems()` or `.viewitems()` (the latter only in 2.7, but it's even closer to Py3's `.items()` behavior) instead of `.items()`, which, in Py2, involves creating a `list` of all the pairs instead of just iterating the `dict` directly as you go.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, just iterate through all the values in the dictionary along with iterating through list dates

When you iterate through a dictionary, you iterate through the keys.

```
for i in dictdates: # i is the key in the dictionary
    print i
    for val in listdates:
        if val in dictdates[i]:
            print val, 'available'
        else:
            print val, 'unavailable'
```

In other words, for every key in the dictionary, check every date in list dates and compare that to the values in the key.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To create the result, I use a nested list comprehension using an OrderedDict on the inner dictionary to keep the dates sorted.

`sorted(list(set(listdates + dictdates[k]))` creates an ordered list of the union between the dictionary dates and those in the `listdates`.  This is then used to iterate through the values for each dictionary entry (e.g. 'S1', 'W24', etc.) and check whether or not the date is there.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d2 = {k: OrderedDict((d, 'unavailable' if d in dictdates[k] else 'available') 
                     for d in  sorted(list(set(listdates + dictdates[k])))) 
      for k in dictdates}
>>> d2
{'S1': OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 28), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 29), 'unavailable')]),
 'W24': OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), 'available'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), 'available'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), 'available'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), 'available')]),
 'W26': OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), 'unavailable'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), 'available'),
              (datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), 'available')])}
```

To print the result:

```
for k, dates in d2.iteritems():
    print(k)
    for d in dates.iteritems():
        print("{0}: {1}".format(d[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), d[1]))
W26
2016-04-20: unavailable
2016-04-21: unavailable
2016-04-22: unavailable
2016-04-23: unavailable
2016-04-24: unavailable
2016-04-25: unavailable
2016-04-26: available
2016-04-27: available
S1
2016-04-20: unavailable
2016-04-21: unavailable
2016-04-22: unavailable
2016-04-23: unavailable
2016-04-24: unavailable
2016-04-25: unavailable
2016-04-26: unavailable
2016-04-27: unavailable
2016-04-28: unavailable
2016-04-29: unavailable
W24
2016-04-23: available
2016-04-24: available
2016-04-25: unavailable
2016-04-26: available
2016-04-27: available
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2016.  Don't write code that doesn't work in python3 :)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime

listdates = [datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), datetime.date(2016, 4, 27)]
dictdates = {'S1': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 26), datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), datetime.date(2016, 4, 28), datetime.date(2016, 4, 29)], 'W26': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 20), datetime.date(2016, 4, 21), datetime.date(2016, 4, 22), datetime.date(2016, 4, 23), datetime.date(2016, 4, 24), datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)], 'W24': [datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)]}

for kk, vv in dictdates.items():
    print(kk)
    for ii in vv:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(ii, ('unavailable' if ii in listdates else 'available')))
```